# unable to reinstall mass package

Tags: r, reinstall, mass

I'm working with R Version 3.3.0 where the most installed packages have the versions 3.3.0, 3.3.2, 3.3.3.
Unfortunately, it seems that I have overwritten the MASS package with the actual version.

I needed the "vars" package and therefore a newer mass version was required. Now I'd like to reestablish the old mass package again.

Is there a solution to this problem? At present I do not want to update all the packages to actual versions as I'm not sure about the consequences...

Here is the Error Message when trying to install an older version...

Thank you!
Tobias

```
install.packages("O:/Shared_with_everyone/Rserver/MASS_7.3-45.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package 'MASS' ...
** package 'MASS' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/Public/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/Public/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="MASS.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="MASS.o lqs.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MASS'
* removing 'C:/Users/Public/R-3.3.0/library/MASS'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Public/R-3.3.0/library/MASS'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Users/Public/R-3.3.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l     "C:\Users\Public\R-3.3.0\library" "O:/Shared_with_everyone/Rserver/MASS_7.3-45.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("O:/Shared_with_everyone/Rserver/MASS_7.3-45.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘O:/Shared_with_everyone/Rserver/MASS_7.3-45.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

under https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib  the relevant old versions can be found, which worked for Windows. Regards, Tobias